# Anime TV show with toys that come to life

Tags: story-identification, anime

I actually don't remember much. I watched it when I couldn't even write a single letter (I was born in 2002) and I don't remember even if it was a TV show instead of an movie. All I remember is it had colors like *Bakugan*.

A kid or a teenager had a toy shop and the plush toys came to life.

In the end, the plush toys sat on what appears to be a trackless roller coaster train with the platform where the people board in that aimed for the sky but wasn't supposed to fire or do anything. Kid did the job and nothing happened except the souls of toys left.

In a later scene He puts one of the toys to a shelf.

He had a happily ever after with the toys. They were dead, but it was all right.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you please be specific about when "years ago" was? Can you identify the style of the animation?

Comment: @DavidW I barely remember anything. I watched that on TV even before I could read and write. The type of animation was colorful anime. It had similar colors like Bakugan which I also watched back then.

Comment: @JonathanIrons DavidW's comment was intended to request "around what year did you watch it?" because we don't know how far "years ago" was, neither the year when you still couldn't write. This is to filter out anime that came later than that year.

Comment: @AndrewT. Considering I was born in 2002 and in that time I couldn't write or something (High possibility. There is a low possibility of me misremembering that). I just don't know honestly.

Comment: I can't identify the story, but you may want to look into the novelist Kenji Miyazawa. The image of a sky-train associated with the afterlife is heavily associated with his work, and it went on to influence quite a number of shows. I don't think *Night on the Galactic Railroad* (the novel the image originates from) is the actual story you're looking for, though it does have an animated adaptation. But lists of anime influenced by his work might still contain what you're looking for.

Comment: It sounds a bit like Super Kuma-san (2003).